# Opencart mysql query optimize

Tags: mysql, optimization, eav

I am using Opencart 2.x with mysql. I have created a custom module for excel export. My query took more than 2 minutes to execute. So I want to optimize my query.

`EXPLAIN` shows the following image

[image]

This is my query

```
SELECT o.order_id, 
       Concat(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname)            AS customer, 
       pov.sku, 
       oo.value, 
       pov.segment, 
       pov.colour, 
       op.quantity, 
       o.shipping_address_1, 
       o.shipping_address_2, 
       o.shipping_city, 
       o.shipping_zone, 
       o.shipping_country, 
       o.shipping_postcode, 
       (SELECT os.NAME 
        FROM   oc_order_status os 
        WHERE  os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id 
               AND os.language_id = '1') AS order_status, 
       (SELECT Count(order_product_id) 
        FROM   oc_order_product 
        WHERE  order_id = o.order_id) AS product_count, 
       (SELECT ot.value 
        FROM   oc_order_total ot 
        WHERE  o.order_id = ot.order_id 
               AND ot.code = 'coupon') AS coupon, 
       (SELECT ot.value 
        FROM   oc_order_total ot 
        WHERE  o.order_id = ot.order_id 
               AND ot.title LIKE '%Shipping Fee%') AS shipping_cost, 
       (SELECT ot.value 
        FROM   oc_order_total ot 
        WHERE  o.order_id = ot.order_id 
               AND ot.title LIKE '%COD Fee (30 INR)%') AS cod, 
       (SELECT ot.value 
        FROM   oc_order_total ot 
        WHERE  o.order_id = ot.order_id 
               AND ot.title = 'CGST') AS cgst, 
       (SELECT ot.value 
        FROM   oc_order_total ot 
        WHERE  o.order_id = ot.order_id 
               AND ot.title = 'SGST') AS sgst, 
       (SELECT ot.value 
        FROM   oc_order_total ot 
        WHERE  o.order_id = ot.order_id 
               AND ot.title LIKE '%Sub-Total%') AS sub_total, 
       o.total, 
       o.currency_code, 
       o.currency_value, 
       o.payment_method, 
       o.date_added, 
       o.date_modified 
FROM   oc_order o 
       LEFT JOIN oc_order_option oo 
              ON ( oo.order_id = o.order_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN oc_product_option_value pov 
              ON ( pov.product_option_value_id = oo.product_option_value_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN oc_order_product op 
              ON( o.order_id = op.order_id ) 
WHERE  o.order_status_id >= 0 
GROUP  BY oo.order_option_id 
ORDER  BY o.order_id DESC
```

Comment: Are you sure that your query gets a correct result? I.e. is all your SELECT columns functionally determined by your GROUP BY column (oo.order_option_id)?

Comment: @Lennart: Yes i got correct results

Comment: Alas, another example of Entity-Attribute-Value run amok.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for slow down of query is clearly visible in the query plan. There are columns need to be indexed, to tune the query performance. In your query you have used **oc_order_option** table which does not have **order_id** column indexed. Index it using following command:

```
ALTER TABLE `oc_order_option` ADD KEY `OrderID` (`order_id`)
```

Same thing is happening with **oc_order_product** and it needs to be tweaked with following command:

```
ALTER TABLE `oc_order_product` ADD KEY `ProductOrderID` (`order_id`)
```

Also you need to tweak **oc_order** as well, use following:

```
ALTER TABLE `oc_order` ADD KEY `OrderStatusID` (`order_status_id`)
```

After implementing the tweaks run your query and see the performance difference.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Kapil actually i got same result. All the tables are correct. But some mistakes in my query. So please give me a suggestion to optimize my query

Comment: You can try reducing dependency on sub-queries and increase dependency on joins. It will be more helpful if you can share the result of **EXPLAIN** on your query after implementing suggested tweak.

Comment: @KapilBhagchandani - a slight improvement would be `INDEX(order_id, quantity)` for `oc_order_product`.  That would make the index "covering".